# Why is this mapped type removing the `?` decorator? How can we achieve a similar result without removing it?

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

#### Problem

We are building a mapped type that excludes properties of type `Function`. Our approach has a problem: it also removes the optional (`?`) decorator from mapped properties.

#### Reproduction

Here is a [simplified reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Keys%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20K%3B%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NoOpMap1%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NoOpMap2%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20Keys%3CT%3E%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20DEMO%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SomeType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20SomeTypeNoOpMap1%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20SomeTypeNoOpMap1%20%3D%20NoOpMap1%3CSomeType%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20SomeTypeNoOpMap2%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20SomeTypeNoOpMap2%20%3D%20NoOpMap2%3CSomeType%3E%3B) of that behavior. `NoOpMap1` behaves as we want it to, and `NoOpMap2` has the problematic behavior.

```js
type NoOpMap1<T> = { // Good. This one does not remove the ?
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

type Keys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K;
}[keyof T];

type NoOpMap2<T> = { // Problem. This one removes the ?
    [K in Keys<T>]: T[K];
};
```

Demo

```js
type SomeType = {
    foo?: string,
}

// type SomeTypeNoOpMap1 = { foo?: string; }
type SomeTypeNoOpMap1 = NoOpMap1<SomeType>;

// type SomeTypeNoOpMap2 = { foo: string; }
type SomeTypeNoOpMap2 = NoOpMap2<SomeType>;
```

`NoOpMap1` behaves as expected. It keeps the `?` decorater on the `foo` property. `NoOpMap2` removes it.

#### Question

Why is `NoOpMap2` removing the `?` decorator? How can we achieve a similar result without removing it?

#### Actual Use Case

Here is the complete type that we are trying to build:

```js
type DataPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

type DataPropertiesOnly<T> = {
  [K in DataPropertyNames<T>]
  : T[K] extends (string | number | boolean) ? T[K]
  : T[K] extends (infer A)[] ? DataPropertiesOnly<A>[]
  : DataPropertiesOnly<T[K]>;
};
```

As mentioned, the above type is responsible for removing properties of type `Function` *without removing the `?` decorator from remaining properties*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to preserve the optional/readonly status of properties in a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), you need to make sure that the compiler perceives the mapping as [homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism).  I know of two ways to do this.

One is for the mapping to be of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` where you are directly mapping over `keyof T` for some `T`, generic or concrete.  You have to have something like `in keyof` appearing *directly* in the type, or it won't count.

```
interface Foo {
    optional?: string;
    readonly viewonly: string;
}

type Homomorphic = { [K in keyof Foo]: 0 };
// type Homomorphic = { 
//   optional?: 0 | undefined; 
//   readonly viewonly: 0; 
// }

type KeyOf<T> = keyof T
type NonHomomorphic = { [K in KeyOf<Foo>]: 0 };
// type NonHomomorphic = { 
//   optional: 0; 
//   viewonly: 0; 
// }
```

The other way to do it is to map over a generic type parameter `K` which has been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof T` for *another generic type parameter* `T`.  So:

```
type GenericConstraint<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: 0 };
type ConstrainedHomomorphic = GenericConstraint<Foo, keyof Foo>;
// type ConstrainedHomomorphic = { 
//   optional?: 0 | undefined; 
//   readonly viewonly: 0; 
// }

type OnlySomeKeysStillHomomorphic = GenericConstraint<Foo, "viewonly">;
// type OnlySomeKeysStillHomomorphic = {
//   readonly viewonly: 0;
// }
```

This latter method was [specifically added](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12826) to get partial mapped types like `Pick<T, K>` to be homomorphic.  And it's this method you need to get your actual use case to work:

```
// unchanged
type DataPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

// quick abort if T is a function or primitive
// otherwise pass to a homomorphic helper type 
type DataPropertiesOnly<T> =
    T extends Function ? never :
    T extends object ? DPO<T, DataPropertyNames<T>> :
    T

// homomorphic helper type
type DPO<T, KT extends keyof T> = {
    [K in KT]
    : T[K] extends (string | number | boolean) ? T[K]
    : T[K] extends (infer A)[] ? DataPropertiesOnly<A>[]
    : DataPropertiesOnly<T[K]>;
}
```

I think that will act the way you want.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Have you studied category theory?

Comment: Not formally; I wish I had a stronger background in it, since it turns out to be [relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#Curry%E2%80%93Howard%E2%80%93Lambek_correspondence) to a lot of the stuff going on in computer programming language type systems.